# HuggingFace Tranfsormers BERTForSequenceClassification with Trainer: How to do multi-output regression?

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am trying to fine-tune a BERT model on a dataset of sentences that has two different real-valued attributes for each sentence. For each one, there is a Valence score and an Arousal score, with real values between 0 and 1. I need to add a classification layer on top of BERTbase, and that layer must have two outputs, and take them both into account for calculating the loss and performing the backpropagation.

Since I am inexperienced, it was suggested to be that I use the Trainer classes / API for this task. I am using BertForSequenceClassification, and I was told that by setting the num_labels parameter to 2, giving the model an input with two feature columns, and overriding the compute_loss method of the Trainer class to force the loss to be computed with both the outputs.

The thing is, when I read the BERTForSequenceClassification documentation, it says that "If config.num_labels == 1 a regression loss is computed (Mean-Square loss), If config.num_labels > 1 a classification loss is computed (Cross-Entropy).". On the other hand, the Trainer documentation has the compute_loss function, which I override. From inspecting the code, I think that by overriding compute_loss and defining it as desired, the "num_labels" parameter on BertForSequenceClassification actually becomes irrelevant and the loss is entirely computed on the redefined method.

I am still afraid that something might be wrong in this adaptation for a 2-output regression model, either with the loss, with the gradient backpropagation or somewhere else. I will leave my code below, and I am incredibly grateful for any help or feedback in using HuggingFace's Trainer for a 2-output regression BERT model.

```
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased', num_labels=2)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased', do_lower_case = True)

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, filename,maxlen):
        nas = ['-1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '#N/A N/A', '#N/A', 'N/A', 'n/a', 'NA', '', '#NA', 'NaN', '-NaN', '']
        data = pd.read_csv(filename,na_values=nas,keep_default_na=False)
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        self.texts = data["Word/Sentence"].tolist()
        self.labels1 = data['Valence'].tolist()
        self.labels2 = data['Arousal'].tolist()
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = { }
        aux = tokenizer(self.texts[idx], max_length=self.maxlen, truncation=True, padding=False)
        item['input_ids'] = torch.tensor(aux['input_ids'])
        item['attention_mask'] = torch.tensor(aux['attention_mask'])
        item['labels'] = torch.tensor( [ self.labels1[idx], self.labels2[idx] ] )
        return item
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.texts)

class MyTrainer(Trainer):
    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        labels = inputs.pop("labels")
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        predictions = outputs[0]
        predictions = torch.sigmoid(predictions)
        loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()
        loss = loss(predictions.view(-1), labels.view(-1))
        return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss

train_dataset = MyDataset("fold1.csv",250)
val_dataset = MyDataset("fold2.csv",250)
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer, padding = "longest", max_length = 250)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          # output directory
    num_train_epochs=4,              # total number of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,   # batch size per device during training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,    # batch size for evaluation
    warmup_steps=50,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    weight_decay=0.01,               # strength of weight decay
    logging_dir='./logs',            # directory for storing logs
    logging_steps=10,
    save_steps=150,
    group_by_length = True,
    evaluation_strategy = "epoch"
)

trainer = MyTrainer(
    model=model,                         # the instantiated :hugging_face: Transformers model to be traine
    args=training_args,                  # training arguments, defined above
    train_dataset=train_dataset,         # training dataset
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,            # evaluation dataset
    data_collator=data_collator,           
)
```

Comment: Just clarifying your question, when you talk about multiple outputs, do you mean that these outputs are independent? This would be called a multi-label classification.

Comment: You're going multi-task learning, right?

Comment: @sbecon Thanks a lot for the replies! So, the outputs are continuous real values between 0 and 1, and they should be considered independent for the purpose of my model. I thought that multi-label classification would only refer to classification problems, and not to regression ones, but I am probably mistaken. I have two outputs, both real values between 0 and 1 (they correspond to different dimensions of sentiment analysis measures)

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 That's a good question. As you can tell, I am quite inexperienced and still learning about these topics, so I don't have a very concrete answer. My supervisor simply says that I need a regression head on top of BERT that outputs two different values, which are present for each sample in the training data. I don't think he wants me to have different task-specific layers for the two targets, just the same network outputting two values instead of one. But maybe this is a worse approach, or I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: I don't know much about `Trainer`, but I've used base PyTorch with HuggingFace Transformers. It's easy enough to have two separate outputs, but I worry about how you would train them. What does your training data look like? Each training instance should have a sentence and two ground-truth numeric values (for the valence and arousal that you mentioned). Is that the case?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Yeah, my training data has 3 "columns", one with the sentence, one with a numeric valence value and another with a numeric arousal value.

Comment: All you need to do is compute the loss for each each of those two variables, add the losses together into another variable, e.g. `sum_loss`, and pass that loss to the optimizer.